# jQuery MMenu: Entire link to open submenu creates an A as a sibling to a SPAN

Tags: submenu, mmenu

For some reason when I replace the A tag with a SPAN mmenu is adding the A link as a sibling to the SPAN rather than a parent.

How do I get MMenu to put the A around the SPAN rather than next to it?

[image: A link as a sibling rather than a parent]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an accident that I caused. Although the implementation is strange (having an A tag as a sibling to the SPAN is strange to me) the issue was me hiding the mm-next class (to hide the next arrow) and it was hiding the A tag as well.